# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: File not found: /path/to/file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

the html part looks like this:

```
...
<form action="/upload/select-single/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="U3Uh3EAYWXaWEiNaWC3zcCQutQe8hGM53u4BTx810o08t1GwOfIJI2ayHCFQFySw">
  <p>
    <label for="id_file_field">File field:</label>
    <input id="id_file_field" name="file_field" type="file" multiple="" required="">
  </p>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
...
```

the selenium test like this:

```
...
btn_choose_file = self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_file_field")
# write file path to field
# to check that I really selected the field, I tried btn_choose_file.click() -> and it works
btn_choose_file.send_keys('/path/to/file')  # -> THIS is the line which seems to cause the problem
# click submit
self.browser.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
...
```

unfortunately when the test is executed this error is raised

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: File not found: /path/to/file

this due to the part where the file path is send to the input element with `btn_choose_file.send_keys('/path/to/file')`

note: the real '/path/to/file' is the following

- */Users/udos/development/trails/processfile/gpx_data/test_data/suite 001 - val poschiavo/Bernina - Le Prese.gpx* (the file exists and I copied the path from the IDE)

very odd behaviour. this test was running before, somehow I managed to break it...

any suggestions what the cause could be?

> **UPDATE**
>  downgrading Firefox from version 55.0.2 to 54.0.1 "fixed" the issue.
> see -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45753912/420953

Comment: Just a suggestion. You may try to remove spaces from path.

Comment: appreciated! I tried that with '/Users/udos/development/trails/processfile/gpx_data/test_data/other/data.gpx', same error :|

Comment: Can you show us the exact HTML and your exact line of code along with the exact error?

Comment: sure. just did. sorry about that. and I also added some comments to the selenium test as well

Comment: Put the file in "/tmp" and without space and try again with a smaller name?

Comment: appreciated! I tried that with '/tmp/data.gpx', same error :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error was due to an update of Firefox to version 55.0.2 (which automatically happened 2 days ago because I have automatic updates configured)

the following geckodriver issue pointed me into this direction

- https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/659
  note: probably this issue was reintroduced in 55.0.x...

I then downgraded my Firefox version to 54.0.1 as described in article

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox
  note: make sure to disable automatic updates as described in that article.

with this, the selenium tests are running again.

Answer (score 3):

One way to work around the issue is to replace all "/" occurances in the filename with "\" ("\\" in python).

This work at least on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

After this bug i installed and used chromewebdriver. Worked like firefox driver and all my tests run smoothly.  I suggest you try it at least it worked like a charm for me